# Ionic /w OneSignal unsubscribe

Tags: ionic-framework, onesignal, unsubscribe

I am currently working with an app that has multiple OneSignal apps. Therefore I need to be able to unsubscribe from one OneSignal app and the subscribe to another. Is this possible? I've tried OneSignal.setSubscription(false) but that doesnt remove the client fully from the subscription. Therefore it isn't possible to subscribe to another onesignal app.

Is there a way to fully unsubscribe from an app?